# Assigning Public IP on VM on XEN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualization, xen

Can anybody guide me in assigning public IP on VM running on Xen.

after xen installation virbr0 with ip 192.168.122.1 has been created. we are having 4 public ip,we need to assign that to each VM.How can i do that.Can anyone guide me in setting IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say IP of the VM has nothing to do with IP of the virbr0. Bridge is bridge, but your parent gw/router needs to know how to reach your public IP on non-private network.